# How to assign the TRESTResponse.JSONValue to an already created TJSONArray?

Tags: json, rest, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I was initialising a `TJSONArray` as:

```
jsonArray := xeroResponse.JSONValue as TJSONArray;
```

but I had forgotten to free the `TRESTResponse`. Now that I'm doing that, the `jsonArray` is being freed as well.

I use the `jsonArray` throughout the Form to run multiple endpoints. So I want to create it in the Form's `OnCreate` event so nothing else owns it. Then I can use it as much as I need and then free it in the Form's `OnDestroy` event.

How do I assign the `xeroResponse.JSONValue` to an already created `TJSONArray`?

And where I am using the `TJSONArray`, I would like to create the `TJSONObject` I am using, so that I can free it directly, as I won't be freeing the `jsonArray` (at that point). I was doing:

```
jObject := jsonArray[x] as TJSONObject;
```

How do I assign the `jsonArray[x]` to an already created `TJSONObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I assign the `xeroResponse.JSONValue` to an already created `TJSONArray`?

You can't.

Reading from `TRESTResponse.JSONValue` creates a new `TJSONValue`-derived object when it parses the response data, and that object is freed when the `TRESTResponse` is freed.  You can't change that process, and you can't take ownership of that object.

So, if you want to keep the parsed JSON object after freeing the `TRESTResponse`, you will have to make a deep copy of the object.

Otherwise, don't use `TRESTResponse.JSONValue` to begin with. Use `TRESTReponse.JSONText` instead and parse it yourself, such as with `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()`.  Then you will have ownership of the object it returns.

> And where I am using the `TJSONArray`, I would like to create the `TJSONObject` I am using, so that I can free it directly, as I won't be freeing the `jsonArray` (at that point). I was doing:
>
> ```
> jObject := jsonArray[x] as TJSONObject;
> ```
>
> How do I assign the `jsonArray[x]` to an already created `TJSONObject`?

You can't do that, either.  When the JSON is parsed and creates a new `TJSONArray`, the parser will also create new objects for the array elements, too.

In short, you can't supply your own pre-created objects to the JSON parser.  If that is what you want, then you need to re-think your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jsonArray := (xeroResponse.JSONValue as TJSONArray).Clone;
```

This will duplicate the object and its contents. You will then be able to free the `xeroResponse` object as well as the `jsonArray` object. Note any of the objects of the array will be owned by `xeroResponse`, so you can use the `.Clone` function on these as well.